# Problemas con el posicionamiento de logo en Header

Tags: html, css

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap para hacer una web y quiero posicionar el logo en el centro del nav y que sobresalga de la barra de navegación, el problema es que el logo no me lo posiciona en en el centro y me lo hecha para derecha

dejo aquí el codigo

```css
.navbarvalues {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.iconnavbar {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}


.logo {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbarvalues">
    <div class="container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search iconnavbar"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="Seis" src="img/logo.svg" class="logo"></a>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-envelope iconnavbar"></i><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Intenta colocar la propiedad ```display``` en ambas clases, ```navbar-nav``` y ```navbar-brand``` , agrega el valor inline-block para posicionar uno al lado del otro

Comment: No hay manera. Es el position absolute del logo lo que joroba todo, pero no encuentro otra manera para que el logo sobresalga del navbar https://imgur.com/JAolsmb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la clase de tu logotipo agregale la propiedad "left" y que su valor sea 50% menos la mitad de lo ancho del logotipo (80px / 2 = 40px). Ej

```
.logo {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 40px);
}
```

Comment: He decidido quitarle el position absolute y el top. Y he cambiado el padding a 0 y ahora el logo se encuentra centrado, pero lo que quiero hacer ahora es que el logotipo sobresalga del navbar por abajo un poco pero no encuentro la manera Así está ahora https://imgur.com/a/bkEKPxO

Comment: Yo te recomendaria dejarlo asi como lo tenias con (position: absolute) y hacerlo un poco hacia abajo con (top: 15px) y el (left) como te lo comente, cuando se necesita que salga un poco del div que lo contiene (.container) es necesario hacerlo asi, recuerda que la posicion absoluta de tu logotipo sera relativa a su contenedor (.container).

Comment: Vale. Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda! Feliz Año Nuevo!

Comment: Igualmente carnal :)

Answer (score 0):

Al menos bootstrap 4 tiene soporte para *flexbox* con lo cual al contenedor padre que tiene a tu logo le pudieras aplicar una clase de este tipo:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <!--aquí tu tag invocando tu logo-->
</div>
```

Con lo cual estarías cubriendo las propiedades y valores de flexbox siguientes:

- `justify-content: center;`
- `align-items: center;`

**Referencia**

- [Bootstrap flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items)

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero el logo continúa en el mismo lugar. No está en el centro

Comment: Entonces de forma manual puedes colocar en una hoja css las 2 propiedades que te menciono para centrar el título @RubenG

Comment: Lo he intentado de esas formas, pero nada. Lo que falla es el position absolute del logo, que también afecta al ml-auto  imgur.com/JAolsmb

Comment: Es que ni el position ni el top son necesarios para lo que buscas, prueba quitar dichas propiedades ya que en conjunto sacan al elemento del DOM del flujo normal y lo posicionan según tu voluntad, entonces prueba removerlas y agregar alguna de las opciones que te indico @RubenG

Comment: Pero he puesto el position absolute y el top 0 para que no deje hueco en la parte de arriba y sobresalga de abajo. Si le quito el absolute y el top, sí que me lo centra, pero cuando pongo dichas propiedades para que no me deje hueco arriba y sobresalga del nav, es cuando se altera. ¿hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo? Esta es una idea de lo que deseo https://imgur.com/a/Rxuun5Y pero el logo en medio

Comment: Para que sobresalga no debería bastar con que le pongas un `z-index: 1;` ?

Comment: Así queda sin valores position absolute ni top 0. He puesto el z-index 1 pero no altera nada. https://imgur.com/a/pGsTbi2

Comment: Le he quitado el padding predeterminado al navbar y me ha quedado así https://imgur.com/a/2QTvHKk sin márgenes, pero lo que ahora quiero es que el logo sobresalga de abajo, he añadido z-index 1 pero no cambia nada